Create a mapped type in TypeScript that allows each mapped key to be assigned a different type?
Is there a way in TypeScript to create a mapped type where each key holds a different type value?
I have several types that should depend on the same set of keys, like this:
type GymFee = {
  id: number;
  feeDescription: string;
  monthlyFee: number;
  registrationFee: number;
  monthsCommitment: number;
  picked: boolean
}

type InterfaceInputs = {
  id: NumberInput;
  feeDescription: TextInput;
  monthlyFee: NumberInput;
  registrationFee: NumberInput;
  monthsCommitment: NumberInput;
  picked: CheckboxInput
};

// ... more types with those keys ...

type TextInput = {
    type: 'text';
    defaultValue: string;
    placeholder: string;
}

type NumberInput = {
    type: 'number';
    defaultValue: number;
    step: number | 'any';
    min: number;
    max: number;
}

type CheckboxInput = {
    type: 'radio';
    defaultChecked: boolean;
}

The syntax I have found so far what allows is this:
type GymFeeKeys =
  | 'id'
  | 'feeDescription'
  | 'monthlyFee'
  | 'registrationFee'
  | 'monthsCommitment'
  | 'picked';

type InterfaceInputFail1 = {
    [Prop in GymFeeKeys]: TextInput // ---> ❌ All the keys hold a value of the same type
}

type InterfaceInputFail2 = Record<GymFeeKeys, CheckboxInput> // ---> ❌ Same limitation

What I'm trying to achieve is that the type system assures me I'm using all the right keys in those derived types every time, and that the list of valid keys is written in just one place as a source of truth.
I've also tried using discriminated unions like this:
type GymFeeKeysTuple =
  | ['id', number]
  | ['feeDescription', string]
  | ['monthlyFee', number]
  | ['registrationFee', number]
  | ['monthsCommitment', number]
  | ['picked', boolean];

type GymFee2= {
    [K in GymFeeKeysTuple[0]]: GymFeeKeysTuple[1]
}
// previous mapped type gives any possible type in GymFeeKeysTuple[1] for each key in GymFeeKeysTuple[0]

(Even if the last piece of code worked, not a big fan of this approach because it would be cumbersome as the tuple would have to account for all the types using these keynames).
Playground with this example

Please [edit] to provide a [mre]. What types are NumberInput, etc? Assuming they're just interfaces, you need some way to map value types to input types, such as a conditional type. See this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer explaining or find a duplicate. If not, what's missing?

Can you make an example of something that you want to fail? Your problem, as phrased, can be solved with just a union type, but I suppose there's some further check that you want to implement

I wanted to keep it brief, those types are in the playground, but I can add them to the post too. They are type aliases right now but they could be changed to interfaces if needed to. In your playground the input type mapping is tied to a primitive type, but I just want to to re-use the keys on an object for another, but having different types assigned to those keys. In your playground if I wanted to assign something different to, for example, "monthsCommitment", because it was also a number primitive in the original object it has to be the same type as the other numbers in the original object

forgot to mention you, @jcalz, also edited your playground to show what I mentioned

@ChristianVincenzoTraina I've probably worded it poorly. I want to use keys in one object in several others, but I don't want those keys to hold the same type

So if you have {foo: number, bar: number}, how is anyone supposed to know whether you want {foo: NumberInput, bar: Bar} or {foo: Bar, bar: NumberInput} or anything else? That information needs to be encoded somewhere... anyway, if such a thing matters to you, please [edit] the question to show it. But you really need to think about how such a thing could even make sense, since on the face of it, it sounds like you're asking the compiler to read your mind. Write a [mre] that shows what you're trying to do, and if it doesn't involve magic, we can help you do it.

You could create a mapping between prop type and corresponding UI types:
Playground
type InputType = [TextInput, string] | [NumberInput, number] | [CheckboxInput, boolean];

type InterfaceInputs = {
  [K in keyof GymFee] : Extract<InputType, [unknown, GymFee[K]]>[0]
};


If your CheckboxInput would contain defaultValue: boolean you could use types of this prop in the inputs:
Playground
type InputType = TextInput | NumberInput | CheckboxInput;

type InterfaceInputs = {
  [K in keyof GymFee] : Extract<InputType, {defaultValue: GymFee[K]}>
};


/* rest of type definitions */

type TextInput = {
    type: 'text';
    defaultValue: string;
    placeholder: string;
}

type NumberInput = {
    type: 'number';
    defaultValue: number;
    step: number | 'any';
    min: number;
    max: number;
}

type CheckboxInput = {
    type: 'radio';
    defaultValue: boolean;
}

You could though make like this without changing CheckboxInput:
Playground
type InputType = TextInput | NumberInput | CheckboxInput;

type InterfaceInputs = {
  [K in keyof GymFee] : Extract<InputType, {defaultValue: GymFee[K]} | {defaultChecked: GymFee[K]}>
};

A template literal would also work like this:
Playground
type InputType = TextInput | NumberInput | CheckboxInput;

type InterfaceInputs = {
  [K in keyof GymFee] : Extract<InputType, {[X: `default${string}`]: GymFee[K]}>
};


I don't necessarily have a key: type tuple in the mapped types (such as default Value) that match a key: type on the original object. Also if I need that some key that shared type with others in the original (e.g: number) hold a different type in the mapped type it would end up being the union of those types: see this playground.

"in the mapped type it would end up being the union of those types" well, how would anything tell otherwise? If number isn't sufficient to pick out the input type, what is?  Given the information in the question, a union is the most reasonable thing to produce here.
